# Raspberry Pi Sense HAT Error: Unorderable [sic] Types

Tags: pi-3, python, sense-hat

I have recently attempted to complete a program for my Raspberry Pi, the purpose of which is to generate a grid of pixels with randomised colours for the Sense HAT, which possesses exactly 64 pixels. Each time I attempted this with randomised x and y coordinates, I was faced with the fact that several pixels would be altered in colour repeatedly, producing, for example 50 coloured pixels, rather than 64, as several were coloured twice.

I attempted to solve this problem by writing the following program, which saves each possible x coordinate and y coordinate to a list and saves each ordered pair, as well; for each instance, the program checks the list of ordered pairs. If the 2 numbers are present, it produces 2 additional random numbers, to prevent overlapping and adds the pair to the list.

The program is as follows:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import random
from time import *

xlist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
ylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
coordlist = []

for i in range(0, 64):
    sense = SenseHat()
    x = random.sample(xlist, 1)
    y = random.sample(ylist, 1)

    for i in coordlist:
        if (x, y) == coordlist[i]:
            x = random.sample(xlist, 1)
            y = random.sample(ylist, 1)
        else:
            pass

    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)

    sense.set_pixel(x, y, r, g, b)

    coordlist.append((x, y))
    print(coordlist)

    sleep(0.5)
```

However, the Python IDE, IDLE, produced the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/SenseHatRandomisedColours.py", line 25, in <module>
    sense.set_pixel(x, y, r, g, b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 335, in set_pixel
    if x > 7 or x < 0:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

It appears to me that the concern is that the numbers I have provided exceed the coordinate limits of the Sense HAT; however, I am not sure of how this could occur, as the individual coordinate lists exclusively possess the numbers 0 to 7, as specified for the Sense HAT. Would there happen to be any solution to this issue? I am utilising Python 3.4.2, as provided within the Raspbian operating system. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Ah let me see.  (1) I have 2 sense hats, but irrelevant here, thus abstracted away. (2) Now your bug is that you want all 64 pixels change colour randomly. That is, no one except god who throws his tricked dices can guess, for any cell, what is its next/new colour, . Take two very unlikely but possibie/probable example cases: (a) all 64 pixels become red. (b) All green. Of course the chance of (a) is about one to one trillion, and [(a) followed by (b)] happening one to 1, 000 ....(followed by.. 27. zeros.  Ah, it is getting  too long, so I will stop for my morning coffee. Cheers.

Comment: The last msg give you the answer: You can "order" a list, but not this "unthinkable" guy: [list() > int()]

Comment: You are welcome. Happy programming.  Cheers.

Comment: why do you randomize the pixel coordinates?